# How to call a view class from another view class in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a project structre as following,

```
..
├── project
│    ├── app1
│    └── app2
│         ├── app2_views
│              ├── main_view.py
│              ├── view1.py
│              ├── view2.py
```

i want to call classes defined in `view1.py` in my `main_view.py`

I have tried the following code,

main.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from app2.app2_views.view1.py import class1

class mainclass(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    class1.view1_data()
```

view1.py

```
from app2.models.py import table1 
from rest_framework import viewsets
from app2.serializers.py import seri1
from django.db.models import Sum

class class1(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def view1_data():
        queryset = table1.objects.values('column')
        serializer_class = seri1
```

seri1.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from app2.models import table1
class seri1(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = table1
        fields = ['column']
```

but i am getting an error in main.py saying

```
should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method
```

since i have already included serializer class in `view1.py` I dont want to do it again in `main_view.py`.
I am new to python, what am i doing wrong here? 
also i want to keep both `view1.py>class1` and `main.py>mainclass` accessible through url(rest framework admin portal) how do i do that?

currently my urls.py is ,

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
from .app2 import view1, main_view

router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'^view1', main_view.mainclass, basename='mis_trx_data')
router.register(r'^main_view', view1.class1, basename='mis_trx_data')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a class level variable called `serializer_class` in your `ModelViewSet`

```
class class1(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    def view1_data():
        queryset = table1.objects.values('column')
        serializer = self.serializer_class(request.data)
```

Ajax request to send the form data to API

```
$.ajax({
    url: api-end-point,
    data: JSON.stringify($("#form").serialize()),
    success: function (E){
        console.log("sucess");
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have already made serializer (```serializer_class```) according to my queryset(```queryset```). Why do i have to make another ```MySerializer``` and what do i specify in that?

Comment: You have `serializer_class` inside a method, which limits the scope of the variable to that method itself. You need to declare a class level variable i.e. before any methods. I have edited my answer to reflect the same.

Comment: where does ```request.data``` come from?

Comment: `request.data` comes from the Ajax call you make to the API endpoint, it has the form data serialized to JSON that you want to save. I have edited my answer to reflect the same.

Comment: i'm getting an error in ```main.py```, not in ```view1.py``` .and even if i do what you have suggested i again get an error in ```main.py``` saying ```should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.```.

Comment: Add `serializer_class` to your `mainclass` the bottom line is, you're missing `serializer_class` in your ModelViewSet which is required.

Comment: even if i do what you have suggested i again get an error in main.py saying should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.

Comment: and how do i call view1.py in main.py... which was my original question?

Comment: You can convert your `mainclass` to `APIView` rather than `ModelViewSet`. Simply do `mainclass(viewsets.APIView)`.